# Error compiling bootstrap.scss - Issue with _root.scss

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4

I am getting an error when compiling my bootstrap sass file. The error looks like this below. When I comment out lines 4 and 8 of _root.scss it works, but that is not an ideal solution. What's going on? - I am running the latest version of Sass 3.5.3

```
Error: Invalid CSS after "...lor}: #{$value}": expected "{", was ";"
        on line 4 of /Users/.../bootstrap-4.0.0/scss/_root.scss
  ...

1: :root {
2:   // Custom variable values only support SassScript inside `#{}`.
3:   @each $color, $value in $colors {
4:     --#{$color}: #{$value};
5:   }
6: 
7:   @each $color, $value in $theme-colors {
8:     --#{$color}: #{$value};
9:   }
```

Comment: Do you use compass? This issue here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/24368 says to not use compass because it uses an older version of sass.

Comment: Not using it, I am compiling it with Dreamweaver.

Comment: I also tried compiling with Scout-App - same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a bug in SASS compiler itself.
Here you have very similar issues:

- https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/24549
- https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/2383

Try this:

```
1: :root {
2:   // Custom variable values only support SassScript inside `#{}`.
3:   @each $color, $value in $colors {
4:     --color-#{$color}: #{$value};
5:   }
6: 
7:   @each $color, $value in $theme-colors {
8:     --color-#{$color}: #{$value};
9:   }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not worried about losing some of the CSS variables, comment out line 4 and 8 of _root.scss then recompile.
Otherwise, add color- onto the beginning of these lines to give 
`--color-#{$color}: #{$value};`

```
@@ -1,11 +1,11 @@
 :root {
   // Custom variable values only support SassScript inside `#{}`.
   @each $color, $value in $colors {
-    --#{$color}: #{$value};
+    --color-#{$color}: #{$value};
   }

   @each $color, $value in $theme-colors {
-    --#{$color}: #{$value};
+    --color-#{$color}: #{$value};
   }

   @each $bp, $value in $grid-breakpoints {
```

[Check the solution](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/24550/commits/37e0dc581e20012574c7cdcfa8a8ac66da2a28ef)

[Update Color in _root.scss](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/24550)

[Can't compile the SCSS](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/24549)

Comment: As I said - that is what I did, and it's not a solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Nov 2019**
error scss/_root.scss (Line 4: Invalid CSS after "...lor}: #{$value}": expected "{", was ";")

I was on Ubuntu 18.04 and using sass-3.7.4.gem

I then realised that
"Ruby Sass has reached end-of-life and should no longer be used"

sudo npm install -g sass
--version
1.23.6 compiled with dart2js 2.6.1

The problem then disappeared and processed the css files in under 5 seconds.